# Creating a DataTemplate in UWP from code

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I'm creating a XAML parser and in order to interact with the UWP classes I need to generate a `DataTemplate` from code.

I have seen that the `DataTemplate` class has a `LoadContent()` method, but how can I use it? Is there a method to specify which content has to be loaded?

By the way, I have try to implement the `IDataTemplate` interface, but since it's ***internal***, I had to derive from `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen that the DataTemplate class has a LoadContent() method, but how can I use it? Is there a method to specify which content has to be loaded?

You can refer to [DataTemplate.LoadContent method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate.loadcontent.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), there is sample code in this document showing how to use the `LoadContent` method to change the appearance of a Border at run time. This is the method to specify which content has to be loaded.

I understand that you may want to create the whole `DataTemplate` in the code behind using XAML Parser, but not load one which exist in the `Resources`, then you can code for example like this:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(
   @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
   <Ellipse Width=""300.5"" Height=""200"" Fill=""Red""/>
   </DataTemplate>");
var template = XamlReader.Load(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
ListView lv = new ListView();
lv.ItemTemplate = template as DataTemplate;
ObservableCollection<int> coll = new ObservableCollection<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    coll.Add(i);
}
lv.ItemsSource = coll;
rootGrid.Children.Add(lv);
```

Here I parsed a `DataTemplate` from string using [XamlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and applied this `DataTemplate` as the `ItemTemplate` of a `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks, Grace! That's OK for 99% of the devs. For me it's not as long as I want my very own XAML parser builds up the Data Template from scratch. What I need is to build the DataTemplate myself. I'm not using XamlReader, but my OmniXAML (v2) that is cross-platform. I'm finding problems with UWP and with WPF because they hide so much that it's almost impossible to control the full process of creating templates.

Comment: @SuperJMN, yes you're right, I think it is impossible in UWP too. Is that possible to use the native method for each different platform like in xamarin? In xamarin it uses `DependencyService` to match each platform. I'm sorry, couldn't help much here.

Comment: No, I'm afraid this isn't the case. Although it's possible, my parser is there to be an alternative: to read and inflate a model without using any other parser. Relying into another parser to inflate a DataTemplate breaks the whole point of it :(